# How to run something every t seconds in C?

Tags: c, timer

In C,  I want a block of statements to be executed repeatedly every *t* seconds. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done in standard C, you need to use some platform-specific API.

One popular choice is POSIX' `alarm()` function.

This is a "pure" aynchronuous solution. It's of course possible to measure and handle time in other ways, but they're still platform-dependent. You could use `sleep()` (again, POSIX) to just block. If you combine that with your desired statements in a loop, that should work too.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a thread or process that runs a loop containing a wait request.

Comment: A thread is definitely the way to do this - the restrictions on what you can safely do in a signal handler (like the one raised by `alarm()`) are so vast that it doesn't seem worth the effort compared to setting up a thread.

Answer (score 1):

If your application runs on Windows, instead, you can use the [SetTimer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with unwind's recommendation for alarm() but don't forget to set another alarm() after you are done with the periodic processing block.